# Как придать импульс объекту(толкнуть) скриптом

Tags: unity3d

Юнити почти не знаю, балуюсь.
Хочу создать, и толкнуть объект в нужном направлении, нормально, с использованием физики, а не с помощью изменения координат скриптом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы **создать** объект в unity, воспользуйтесь методом `Instantiate`. При этом можно создать префаб, сделать в скрипте `public GameObject myObj` поле, и через инспектор перетянуть префаб на это поле. Ну и в коде написать: `Instantiate(myObj, ...)`.

Физическое тело в unity - `GameObject` с компонентом `RigidBody` или `RigidBody2D` на нем для симуляции 3D и 2D физики соответственно.

Чтоб **передать импульс физическому телу**, воспользуйтесь методом `RigidBody.AddForce` или `RigidBody2D.AddForce`. Первым параметром он принимает вектор силы/импульса, а вторым - enum `ForceMode`, который может принимать значения `Force`, `Impulse` и д.р.

Справка: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Конечно, сначала нужно получить компонент `RigidBody` или `RigidBody2D` данного тела через `GetComponent`.